# "Mega" Menu HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, menu

I would like to conceive an html menu to apply on a sharepoint website

It is a little complicated to explain so there is a Schema
[Picture of the Menu wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW3sH.png)

Do you have an example of css to achieve that?
The structure of the html is like that :

```html
ID MENU          #zz12_TopNavigationMenu
  UL (level 1)      #zz13_RootAspMenu
   LI      .static
  A
    SPAN
   SPAN   .menu-item-text
   LI      .static.dynamic-children
  A
    SPAN
   SPAN    .menu-item-text
   UL (Level 2)    .dynamic
     LI      .dynamic dynamic-children
    A
      SPAN
     SPAN   .menu-item-text
     UL (Level 3) .dynamic
      LI    .dynamic
        A
         SPAN
       SPAN  .menu-item-text
      LI
        A 
          SPAN
         SPAN 
      LI
    LI - 
     UL (Level 3)
      LI 
      LI
      LI
      
    LI - Practical information
     UL (Level 3)
      LI 
      LI
      LI
      LI
```

Thank you

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Yes I tried and for the moment this is what I have but as it's a part of a masterpage in sharepoint it is not easy to share 

http://i.imgur.com/jk0SUNn.png

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
<div class="tabs">

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>

       <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>

       <div class="content">`enter code here`
           stuff
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>

       <div class="content">
           stuff
       </div> 
   </div>

</div>
```

Css

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;`enter code here`
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```